# tcpdump - resolve IP and skip resolving ports

Tags: tcpdump

How to tell `tcpdump` to resolve names and leave the port numbers unresolved?

From man:

```
-n     Don’t convert host addresses to names.  This can be used to avoid DNS lookups.
-nn    Don’t convert protocol and port numbers etc. to names either.
```

setting `tcpdump -nn` skips the resolution for *both* addresses and ports.

Answer (score 20):

Have you tried `-nnvvS` (Don't resolve DNS or Port names, be more verbose when printing info, print the absolute sequence numbers)

Src: [http://www.ihtb.org/security/tcpdump-explained.txt](http://web.archive.org/web/20170101183358/http://www.ihtb.org/security/tcpdump-explained.txt) (archived, original link dead)

Comment: Just confirming that this doesn't work for me either on a CentOS 6.x system running tcpdump version: 4.1-PRE-CVS_2012_03_26.